# Bottom border in table is cut by vertical border

Tags: html, css

I have a table where I need a vertical spacing between cells AND a bottom border that is not cut by the vertical spacing. If I use for example this CSS:

```
table td {
   border-right: 15px solid transparent;
}
table tr {
    border-bottom: thin solid #d6d6d6;     
}
```

... the bottom border is cut by the vertical borders. I have also tried border-spacing (and 'border-collapse: separate') with no luck. I really need the bottom border to span uncut under all cells in a row. Is there any way to accomplish this?

EDITED:
As most answers suggest that I use padding, I add this image to show what happens. An image within a cell extends beyond the padding and ends up to close to the next cell (I use Firebug to select the td element and to show the right padding here:

[image]

So I need to accomplish a border-spacing that keeps the cell content at a distance from the necxt cell AND without cutting the bottom border.

Comment: add html too or provide fiddle

Comment: have you tried *margin* property?

Comment: @Atula margin doesn't works in `<td>`

Comment: ok thanks for telling

Comment: can you show all css and html for your table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
/* COLLAPSE CELLS */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

/* SPACE CELLS */
table td:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right: 15px;
}

/* BORDER BOTTOM */
table td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/300/300/2"></td>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for answering. Unfortunately the 'padding-riight' does not do the trick. Both text and images in the cell extends beyond the padding and ends up to close to the next cell. With my transparent border it looks perfect, except for the bottom border that is cut between every cell.

Comment: it should not, see my edit. You must have some other CSS rules that are breaking your layout

Comment: @TBJ you should add a jsFiddle/Plunker that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use transparent border's just add spacing at bottom of cells with padding.

```
table td {
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that I follow what you mean. I really ned to have a spacing between the cells (horisontally) as well as a bottom border.

Comment: if you need horizontal spacing then use left and right padding for for botton space use bottom padding

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Apolo, you gave me the solution in the comment. There was in fact another CSS rule ( `table{width: 100%;}` ), provided by the framework (I use Drupal 7), that broke my own rule. Problem solved.